# Show a skeleton placeholder until Facebook Comments component loads completely in React (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, facebook-social-plugins

Using Next.js, I want to show a skeleton placeholder until Facebook Comments component loads completely.

Here is the code.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { initFacebook } from "../utils/initFacebook";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadFacebook = async () => {
      await initFacebook();
      setLoaded(true);
    };

    loadFacebook();
  }, []);

  const skeletonComponent = (
    <div>
      <h1>Some skeleton placeholder</h1>
    </div>
  );
  const facebookComponent = (
    <div
      className="fb-comments"
      data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator"
      data-width="580"
      data-numposts="10"
    />
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {loaded ? facebookComponent : skeletonComponent}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm using the state to switch between two components.

But the skeleton component does not wait until the Facebook component is fully loaded, and therefore users see the blank screen for about 3-5 seconds.

How should I go about having the skeleton component wait out until the Facebook component is visible?

The full code is available on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-dust-znt0h).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that the promise from `initFacebook` resolves too quickly. One can still see your "loading skeleton" flashing. Watching the network activity one can see that the delay is due to request sent to this url: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/feedback.php .... This must be happening inside some Facebook code you're loading into your page, so it might be tricky to get a promise from that.

Comment: @tromgy Currently I'm using `setTimeout` to estimate the loading time, and I guess that will have to do for the time being.